# Confused about "implements Runnable"

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

Hello have only a few days with Java and android here. I am a bit confused about exactly how the "implements runnable" actually works example:

```
public class DrawableSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

[...]

public void resume(){
    isRunning = true;
    mThread = new Thread(this);
    mThread.start(); //start the animation
    parseParameters(); //<== Here is my problem
}

public void run() {
    while (isRunning == true){
        if (!mHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
         continue;
        }
        Canvas canvas = mHolder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
        canvas.drawPath(PenPath, PenPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(CursorPath, CursorPaint);
        mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}
public void parseParameters() {
  [...]
  [ The rest of my code here  modifying PenPath and CursorPath, etc ]

}
```

I am embarrassed to ask, but I thought that after mThread.start(); a new thread would be started running a loop in the run method. instead what I get is the run method only executed after my  parseParameters() method terminates.
What I wanted to achieve is to have the canvas on a drawing loop thread and externally modify the parameters of the drawing paths to generate my animation.
I am sure this is very elemental, but I have been unable to understand this for a few hours. The docs are not helping.

Any pointer would help a lot. Cheers guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in this situation you would not want to implement any kind of loop yourself. You would want to override the [onDraw(Canvas canvas)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) in your custom view. With this you can force onDraw to be called by calling [invalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) on your view from anywhere. You could accept parameters from an outside source as well.

Answer (score 6):

The meaning of `implements Runnable` is that this class reacts to the methods defined in the Runnable interface, and those may be passed to the constructor of `Thread` as you do.

Now, a new thread is not immediately executed, and it is very possible that the current thread will continue to execute some function before the system will switch to the other thread's context.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I realized that the thread is not guaranteed to start immediately. So I tried to lock my other methods with a loop and a boolean until the run() method gets executed and the boolean switched. But the Run() method never gets executed so the loop go on infinitely. hmm sorry for the stupid question,  still not getting it.

Comment: try making isRunning `volatile`, and where do you change its value to false? I didn't see it in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I did not copy the entire code .. Will try  making it volatile

Answer (score 5):

`mThread.start();` only tells Java (and the OS) to make the thread eligible to run.  There's no guarantee that the thread will start right away.  In fact, especially on a single-core system, the thread often won't start running til the next time the OS jumps in and switches tasks/threads, so when it'll actually start can be pretty much "when it feels like it".

Answer (score 3):

`Class X ... implements Runnable` only do one single thing, namely promise that X will provide what the Runnable interface say will be there.  In other words, it is an indication that X will conform to the *contract* that a Java interface - here Runnable - is.

For `Runnable` the only thing the contract say, is that X will provide a `void run()` method.

The trick here is recognizing that the `Thread` constructor called require a Runnable, so it can be certain there is a `run()` method to invoke.  Note that when the new thread has started, your program now has *two* places where things happen.  You need to be certain to assign the work correctly, so it happens in the correct thread.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of `Runnable` is basically correct.

The problem is that you are making incorrect assumptions about what `Thread.start()` does.  In reality, Thread.start() causes the new native thread and its stack to be created, and makes the thread *eligible* to run.  But it is *implementation dependent* whether the new thread is scheduled and runs before the `start` call returns to the original thread ... or not.

The other problem with your code is that `run()` method is essentially a CPU gobbling polling loop.  Unless you are running on a platform with multiple cores, your application's behaviour is going to be very "laggy" ... and it will rapidly drain the batteries.  You need to make it event driven, with the `run()` method waiting until there is something to actually draw.

I don't know enough about Android to tell you how to implement that, but what your app is currently doing looks very wrong to me.